# Add "field" of table name to SQL results from UNION?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

If I have a simple union

```
select name, phone from users union select name, phone from vendors;
```

Is there a way to add the table name to the results?

So instead of

```
+--------+-------+
| name   | phone |
+--------+-------+
| Jim    | 123...|
| Macy's | 345...|
+--------+-------+
```

I'd get

```
+--------+-------+---------+
| name   | phone | table   |
+--------+-------+---------+
| Jim    | 123...| users   |
| Macy's | 345...| vendors |
+--------+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
select name, phone, 'users' as table_name from users
union
select name, phone, 'vendors' as table_name from vendors;
```

Better solution will be to use `union all`, so server will not be checking for distinct values

```
select name, phone, 'users' as table_name from users
union all
select name, phone, 'vendors' as table_name from vendors;
```

Comment: Oh wow, I actually thought of that but figured it was way too simple. Thanks!

Comment: The difference would be if a user and vendor had the same info, I'd get both results with distinct table_name? Or am I interpretting UNION ALL wrong?

Comment: Thank you @MartinSmith, yes, it's actually better. When you're using `union` server will try to give you only distinct results. Actually, it will be the same resultset, but it's better not to bother server with extra work :)

Comment: @user1484099 - The different `table_name` means there definitely won't be any duplication between the two sets. If you want to remove duplication within either set you would be better off using `DISTINCT` on the relevant individual queries and combining them with `UNION ALL`

Comment: I don't actually want to use DISTINCT in this case, but thank you, that's good information.

Comment: I found this answer to part of my question but have an added twist:  I have about 120 tables that I want to merge and don't want to type the names of each table.  Even better, I would like to create a look-up table with a simple integer key that identifies the original table name and then simply add a foreign key column to the large table of merged rows.