# From Which Table the data has been retrieved

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT username,
       password,
FROM table1
WHERE username = :username
UNION ALL
SELECT username,
       password,
FROM table2
WHERE username = :username
```

I want to find from which table the data as been retrieved whether from table1 or table2
And ya the inserted data in these tables are unique

Thanks in advance

Comment: is both table having different user names?

Comment: yes... but want to find whats the table name from which the data is obtained

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992315/add-field-of-table-name-to-sql-results-from-union

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a column with this information:

```
SELECT 'table1' as which, username, password
FROM table1
WHERE username = :username
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table2' as which, username, password
FROM table2
WHERE username = :username;
```

Comment: can u tell me how can i store the obtained table name in string...$getrole = $row['which']; i m doing this but i m getting null value

Comment: @HardikAmal . . . Something like the code in your comment should work.  That is a different question, and you can ask another question with the focus on the application code.

Comment: some syntax error was there got solved...thanks a lot brother for the help