# Create SQLite view as a union with source table name field

Tags: sql, sqlite

A SQLite database has an undefined number of tables having the same schema. A view is required that is a union of all these tables with the addition of a field set to the name of the source table.

*Note that the table names are unknown as are their column names. All that can be assumed is that all tables have the same schema (i.e. the same columns).*

Is it possible to do this in SQLite3?

---

I can build a view manually given prior knowledge:

```
create view V(A,B,C) as select 'A' as Tbl, * from A union select 'B' as Tbl, * from B ...
```

I can find the tables (optional: only table names beginning with `X`):

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master where type='table' and name like 'X';
```

(as similar questions suggest: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992315), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429109).)

I can [find the column names of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604939), `t`:

```
pragma table_info(t)
```

I can use the above information to build the query outside *SQLite*, in this case using `bash`, and then apply it to the database:

```
# build a select for each table
selects=()
for table in $(sqlite3 "$DB" "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master where type='table'")
do
    selects+=("select '$table' as Tbl, * from $table")
done

# Column names for new view, first is source table name followed
# by the table's column names (of the last table, but all assumed to be the same)
columns=(Tbl $(sqlite3 "$DB" "pragma table_info($table)" | awk -F '|' '{print $2}'))

# Build union query
set -o noglob
query=''
for union in "${selects[@]::${#selects[@]}-1}"
do
    query+="$union union all "
done
query+="${selects[-1]}"

sqlite3 "$DB" "create view AllTables($(IFS=,;echo "${columns[*]}")) as $query"
```

Ideally I would prefer to do this from within SQLite3 without having to meta-program it in a shell.

---